# Sign up using Firebase cloud functions and Typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase

Im trying to write a Sign up cloud function in typescript. When i try to call `.auth()` on my firebase app, it gives me this compilation error `Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'FirebaseNamespace'.ts(2339)`.

Heres the import: `import { firebase } from "@firebase/app";`

Heres the function:

```
app.post("/signup", async (req, res) => {
  try{
    const userJson =  {
      email: req.body.email,
      displayName: req.body.displayName,
      password: req.body.password,
      confirmPassword: req.body.confirmPassword,
    };
    const user = await firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userJson.email, userJson.password)
    const displayName: string = user.data()?.displayName;
    res.json({ message: `user ${displayName} succesfuly created` });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using the syntax from the client library. The cloud functions have a different format.

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
```

```
admin
  .auth()
  .createUser({
    email: 'user@example.com',
    emailVerified: false,
    phoneNumber: '+11234567890',
    password: 'secretPassword',
    displayName: 'John Doe',
    photoURL: 'http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png',
    disabled: false,
  })
```

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user

Comment: Alright thanks, it works! Im following this tutorial that doesnt use TS and the guy wrote it like that (the import was different), any idea why he would prefer the client library?

Comment: Great -- you can mark it as correct by using the green check mark and if it was a helpful answer, you can also upvote using the arrow next to the answer. In terms of using the client vs. server library, as far as I know, you can only user the Admin SDK on the server side.